# Copy one field to another: "Subquery returns more than 1 row"

Tags: subquery

here we have the query:

```
UPDATE ps_product_lang_copy 
    SET description =
    ( SELECT description
        FROM ( SELECT description
                FROM `ps_product_lang_copy`
                    WHERE id_lang = 5
                    ) t
    )
    WHERE id_lang IN (1,2,3,4);
```

I'm trying to do this thing:

i've a field on a table, called 'description'

every row in this table has an 'id_lang'

i wish to copy, for every row and not only one, the field 'description' from id_lang = 5 to 'description' of others rows with id_lang IN (1,2,3,4) but the system, with that query told me: **Subquery returns more than 1 row**

i read a lot here on stack overflow but really can't fix my code :(

EDIT:

SOLVED by myself, i'll post here to help each others

```
    UPDATE ps_product_lang
    INNER JOIN ps_product_lang_copy
    ON ps_product_lang.id_product = ps_product_lang_copy.id_product
    SET ps_product_lang.description = ps_product_lang_copy.description
    WHERE ps_product_lang_copy.id_lang = 5
```

ciuss

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

```
UPDATE ps_product_lang
INNER JOIN ps_product_lang_copy
ON ps_product_lang.id_product = ps_product_lang_copy.id_product
SET ps_product_lang.description = ps_product_lang_copy.description
WHERE ps_product_lang_copy.id_lang = 5
```

Comment: i didn't add additional information.... i solved the problem, bro, so don't understand what u mean